# SQL query to populate missing values using lead and lag

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a new column that fills in the nulls below.  I tried using leads and lags but isn't turning out right.  Basically trying to figure out who is in "possession" of the record, given the TransferFrom and TransferTo columns and sequence of events. For instance, 35 was in possession of the record until they transferred it to 57. My current query will only populate 35 in record 2 since it only leads by one record.  I need the query to populate all records prior to this as well if 35 is the first value found in the TransferFrom column. Spark SQL...Any ideas?

Create table script:

```
CREATE TABLE results (
 OrderID int
,TransferFrom string
,TransferTo string
,ActionTime timestamp)

INSERT INTO results

VALUES
(1,null,null,'2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
(1,null,null,'2020-01-02 00:00:00'),
(1,null,null,'2020-01-03 00:00:00'),
(1,'35','57','2020-01-04 00:00:00'),
(1,null,null,'2020-01-05 00:00:00'),
(1,null,null,'2020-01-06 00:00:00'),
(1,'57','45','2020-01-07 00:00:00'),
(1,null,null,'2020-01-08 00:00:00'),
(1,null,null,'2020-01-09 00:00:00'),
(1,null,null,'2020-01-10 00:00:00')
```

Current query that doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
     ,coalesce(
        lead(TransferFrom) over (partition by OrderID order by ActionTime)
       ,TransferFrom
       ,lag(TransferTo) over (partition by OrderID order by ActionTime)) as NewColumn
FROM results
```

Current query result that is incorrect:

[image]

Desired query result:

[image]

Comment: The query depends on the specific database. Which one are you using?

Comment: For Jan 4th, does the value `57` comes from row #3 or row #6? What do you do if those values are different?

Comment: Please read the info under the tag: [tag:sql] (and act upon the info give there)

Comment: "Current query that doesn't work" why not?, and "Current query result that is incorrect" Why is it incorrect?  You did not give expected output, so one can only guess why it's wrong/incorrect, because "desired" is the question...

Comment: @TheImpaler updates have been made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of a funky situation but this works for your sample data. Ideally it would be better to fix the process that is not inserting values consistently so you don't have to jump through these hoops.

```
select r.*
    , NewColumn = coalesce(x.TransferFrom, y.TransferTo)
from results r
outer apply
(
    select top 1 TransferFrom
    from results r2 
    where r2.ActionTime >= r.ActionTime
        and r2.TransferFrom is not null
    order by r2.ActionTime
) x --this will get the values for all the rows that have a preceeding NULL
outer apply
(
    select top 1 TransferTo
    from results r3 
    where r3.ActionTime <= r.ActionTime
        and r3.TransferTo is not null
    order by r3.ActionTime desc
) y --this will get the values for the last rows that don't have a value.
order by r.ActionTime
```

Comment: Yes, this will work. In case both values (future & past) are different it will prioritize the future one.

Comment: @SeanLange I forgot to mention the partition column

Comment: @eloh You forgot an important part of the question. Accept this one, and ask a new quwstion.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely sub-optimal for spark SQL, but it got me the right answer.

```
with cte1 as (
    select *
    from results
)
, cte2 as (
    select *
    from cte1
    where TransferFrom is not null
    or TransferTo is not null
    order by ActionTime
)
, cte3 as (
    select distinct OrderID, TransferFrom as Team from cte2
    union
    select distinct OrderID, TransferTo as Team from cte2
)
, cte4 as (
    select a.*
    ,ifnull(timestampadd(MICROSECOND, 1, c.ActionTime),'2000-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000') as StartTime
    ,ifnull(b.ActionTime,'9999-12-31T00:00:00.000+0000') as EndTime
    from cte3 as a
    left join cte2 as b
      on a.OrderID = b.OrderID
      and a.Team = b.TransferFrom
    left join cte2 as c
      on a.OrderID = c.OrderID
      and a.Team = c.TransferTo
    order by OrderID, StartTime
)
, cte5 as (
    select a.*, b.Team
    from cte1 as a
    join cte4 as b
      on a.OrderID = b.OrderID
      and a.ActionTime between b.StartTime and b.EndTime
)

select * 
from cte5
order by 1, 4
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).